# B85M-K Motherboard 2x8GB ram DDR3 no monitor signal

Tags: memory, motherboard

Recently I bought the B85M-K motherboard and also buy 2 Kingston ram sticks.

2 stick of Kingston ram: 8GB DDR3 bus 1600(KVR16n11/8)

When I install both RAMs, the computer turns on but the monitor does not show a picture.
But when I test the RAMs alone, the computer works without any problems.

Reset Bios for several and no luck!

Power = Cooler master rs-390-pmsr-a3 390W

Note that I used this 16 GB of RAM and CPU + PSU on another motherboard without any problems.

I disconnected Hard drive, graphic card, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The RAM you bought
[KVR16n11/8](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr16n11_8.pdf)
is **DDR3**-1600.

The Crucial site for your motherboard
[B85M-K](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/b85m-k)
recommends only **DDR3L**-1600.

DDR3 is not compatible with DDR3L since DDR3 is single voltage capable memory
which operates only at 1.5V and can only be used with a DDR3 slot,
since only a DDR3 slot can provide that voltage.
DDR3L supports dual voltages (1.35V on a DDR3L slot and 1.5V on a DDR3 slot),
meaning that a DDR3L stick can work on both DDR3 and DDR3L slots.

The two types, DDR3L and DDR3, are not compatible, which is the problem.
DDR3 RAM is not compatible with DDR3L slot while DDR3L memory stick can work on
a DDR3 slot too.

It might be that one DDR3 stick works because it can get enough voltage,
but the two sticks don't work since there is not enough voltage for both.

I suggest returning your RAM (and then perhaps buying Crucial).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but base on asus vendor list: "https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85M-K/B88_2DIMM_total_report_150909.pdf" , i can see some model with pair DDR3 model.
like: KHX1600C10D3B1K2/16G

Comment: Yes, but not for your computer model.

Comment: That list for B85M-K motherboards.

Comment: RAM compatibility is dependent on many parameters. I trust Crucial, they are never wrong.

Comment: Since you need to change RAM sticks anyway, buy DDR3L from a vendor that guarantees compatibility with your motherboard. If it works, then the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The 8GB Kingston sticks are not listed in the QVL for that MB.

https://www.asus.com/supportonly/B85M-K/HelpDesk_QVL/

They still might work, but there could be a reason they're not on the list.

Be sure you have them seated well, and spray the sockets with some contact cleaner (like https://www.wd40.com/products/contact-cleaner/ ) to be sure it's not just a bad connection.  Lost count of how many times that has "fixed" an issue like this for me over the years.